# can't import xml file

Tags: import

While i upload  xml file to my site ,  the following error message occur and uploading fail

> Sorry, there has been an error. File
>   is empty. Please upload something more
>   substantial. This error could also be
>   caused by uploads being disabled in
>   your php.ini or by post_max_size being
>   defined as smaller than
>   upload_max_filesize in php.ini

I can't edit the stuff mentioned in above (php.ini) becoz of mine is hosted on shared hosting 
and i don't wanna migrate from  database or something like that .  Is there a ways from migrating from wordpress scope ???

Comment: "file empty" - have you checked the file?

Answer (score 2):

finally i  split my xml file with wxr splitter and did as
http://www.rangerpretzel.com/content/view/20/1/
inform then import it .

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.
I think this error is Because of memory limit.

So, I have no access to my php.ini file. So I created my own php.ini file with the following in it and added to my wp-admin folder.

memory_limit = 128M

Its work for me !!